# "methods inside method" - class python2

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, class

I have this situation:

```
class ROUTER:
   ...
   def utils(self):
      def update(..) ...
      def reboot(..) ...
```

and I would like to invoke the sub methods of utils like this:

```
a=ROUTER()
a.utils.reboot()
```

but not work (`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'inf`). Where am I wrong?
Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as "methods inside methods" in Python. You can have functions defined inside methods but they are not accessible from outside the method. For this to work `a.utils.reboot()` it means that `a.utils` is an attribute or property of `a`, and that `a.utils` is an object, and that object must have a `reboot` method

Comment: And "not work" is not a sufficient problem description. Show what error or output/result you get and what you would expect.

Comment: @Anentropic and how could I "structure" this problem? Because I would like such a "hierarchy". Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: You are going about this backwards, the usage can emerge from necessity of the code. Why do you want this?  Why not just `a.reboot()`?

Comment: @Anentropic because as I have already said, I want something neat and clean. Since it will have many methods I decided to group them into various macro categories where each macro category (in the example "utils") will contain all the methods for the "utils" of the router. Then there will be a "wifi" macro-category where its content will be inherent only to wifi, etc., etc. For this I want something like this ... it is more "understandable" also in writing the code

Comment: The problem is that in order to implement this the `utils.*` methods will have to live in a separate class from the `wifi.*` methods, and both of them will be separate from the Router class. There can be good reasons for factoring code out into multiple smaller classes, but it is quite likely you can make an over-complicated mess trying to get it to work if your idea of what the interface should look like does not fit well with the practical needs of the code itself.

Comment: Yes, because there are many methods ... sometimes there are the same "functions" but which are applied in different areas (such as "reboot" can be both of the wifi and of the router itself). So, instead of throwing everything into one "cauldron" I decided to "break it down" into smaller but neat pieces. In addition, the final interface will also benefit as it will be much clearer just by looking at it ... just look at the methods to which attributes are applied

Comment: Also, these "little" classes will only have to inherit two attributes ... a session Requests and the router url ... that's it

Comment: moreover, behind everything I built a backend (simple functions) that can be called up by the methods and I can reuse these functions for any other project (always in the router area, of course). All I need to do is create a new interface (with classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the basic approach you need in order to implement your desired interface:

```py
class Utils:
    def update(...): ...

    def reboot(...): ...


class Router:
   def __init__(...):
       self.utils = Utils(...)


myrouter = Router()
myrouter.utils.reboot()
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... and if I would also like to pass the instance (some attributes) to the new class?

Comment: you can `self.utils = Utils(router=self)` and then in `Utils` class define an init method like `def __init__(self, router): self.router=router`

Comment: and using inherited classes? Wouldn't that be better?

Comment: How would that help?  You could make the child objects subclasses of `Router` but then you expose a weird unwanted recursive structure in the interface e.g. `myrouter.utils.utils.wifi.utils.reboot()` would be possible. And you would still have to pass the parent instance into the child constructor.

Comment: Ehm yes ... in fact, you are right. Thanks very much